# How to make oauth2 server generating JWT tokens in order to avoid store tokens

Tags: python, jwt, authlib

I am using [authlib](https://docs.authlib.org) to develop an auth server.

The default Bearer token creation is a random string that is stored in database.

What I want is generate a JWT and no store it on database.

I am using `OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_GENERATOR` option to generate token:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from authlib.jose import jwt

def gen_token(*args, **kwargs):
    key_location = '/path/to/key/id_rsa'

    header = {'alg': 'RS256'}
    payload = {
        'iat': datetime.utcnow(),
        'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=3600)
    }
    t = jwt.encode(header, payload, open(key_location, 'r').read())
    return t
```

How can I avoid store generated token using `client_credentials` grant?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid saving token by passing a "do nothing" `save_token` function.

https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/authorization-server.html#server

```
def save_token(token, request):
    pass

server = AuthorizationServer(..., save_token=save_token)
```